# Prevent JqueryUI Accordion Click From Deselecting Text In Contenteditable Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am currently using `document.execCommand()` to style text in a contenteditable div.  I'd like to put the controlling elements in a JqueryUI accordion, however it is behaving strangely with select menus.

Because my select element is placed on a pane of a JqueryUI accordion, the selected text in the contenteditable field is deselected as soon as the mousedown event is fired.  Is there a way to disable / block propegation of the mousedown event after the initial hit on the select element?  Or more importantly any way to be able to click the select menu, and select an item to fire my `document.execCommand()` through the select element's `onchange` event before the text in the contenteditable text is deselected?

I've tried the following, but it also stops the select menu from opening.  `#propertiesPanel` is the actual accordion pane where the select menu is located.

Also, just to clarify, the pane is already open, I select text in the contenteditable div, and I'm only trying to click the select element to drop down and change text size (as an example).  The exact same procedure does not deselect the text when the JqueryUI accordion is not being used.

```
$('#propertiesPanel').mousedown(
    function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
);
```

The simple stopPropegation version of the above doesn't do anything at all.

```
$('#propertiesPanel').mousedown(
    function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
);
```

Additionally, I just tried this and it doesn't work, but perhaps this is more acceptable approach than altering events?

```
$("#propertiesPanel").children().css({userSelect: 'none'});
```

Another approach I'm trying is using `return false` on the entire panel.  It doesn't deselect the text, however it won't allow the select element to drop down either.

```
$('#propertiesPanel').mousedown(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use something like,

```
$(".something").click(function() {
  $("input.whatever").focus();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how that would work in this situation?  The idea is not to change the focus, as this deselects the text from the contenteditable div.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding a solution.  It is a pretty heavy solution, but seems to work cross browser using the rangy plugin.

https://github.com/timdown/rangy

```
    var savedSel = null;
    function saveSelection() {
        if (savedSel) {
            rangy.removeMarkers(savedSel);
        }
        savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
    }
    function restoreSelection() {
        if (savedSel) {
            rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel, true);
            savedSel = null;
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        // Turn multiple selections on in IE
        try {
            document.execCommand("MultipleSelection", null, true);
        } catch(ex) {}
        rangy.init();
    }
```

I call `saveSelection()` on mousedown & `restoreSelection()`, just before document.execCommand on the actual `onchange` event.  I'll leave this question open for anyone else who has a lighter / more elegant solution.